# How can I export existing AWS ELB policies? undefined method 'reduce'

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

We want to export our ELB configurations for re-use. I can get the ELB configs with:

```
all_elbs = Fog::AWS::ELB.load_balancers.all()
```

But this returns a failure:

```
all_policies = Fog::AWS::ELB.policies.all()
#=> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fog-aws-0.0.6/lib/fog/aws/models/elb/policies.rb:20:
#=> in `munged_data': undefined method `reduce' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to recreate a ELB based on an existing ELB.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that on line 20 of `policies.rb` there is code like `foo.reduce` and `foo` happens to be `nil`.

If we look at the source code of the gem, we see:

```
def munged_data
  data.reduce([]){ |m,e|  # line 20
```

So, the problem is that `data` is `nil` when the `munged_data` method is called. We see on line 8 of the same file that `data` is defined via a simple `attr_accessor` call. I cannot tell for sure where that should have been set. (There are 227 instances of `@data =` or `data =` in the gem.) This seems like a bug in the AWS gem, unless you were supposed to call some method before calling `.all` on `policies`.

---

Tracing further, we see that `policies` is defined in `load_balancer.rb` on line 154 as:

```
def policies
  Fog::AWS::ELB::Policies.new({
    :data => policy_descriptions,
    :service => service,
    :load_balancer => self
  })
end
```

Assuming that the `data` passed to the method is used directly as the `@data` instance variable, then the problem is that `policy_descriptions` returned `nil`.

The implementation of `policy_descriptions` is:

```
def policy_descriptions
  requires :id
  @policy_descriptions ||= service.describe_load_balancer_policies(id).body["DescribeLoadBalancerPoliciesResult"]["PolicyDescriptions"]
end
```

If `service.describe_load_balancer_policies(id).body["DescribeLoadBalancerPoliciesResult"]` returned `nil` (or any object that did not have a `[]` method) this method would have thrown an error. So, my deduction is that this returned something like a hash, but that hash has no `"PolicyDescriptions"` key.

From there...I don't know.